# How to use environment variables for Android and iOS in React Native?

Tags: android, ios, react-native

I am currently building an app in React Native and using Auth0 for authentication. The configuration needs to use some variables inside the Android code. I do not know too much about deployment, but I would like to know what is the easiest way to substitute environment variables inside Android and iOS for different development and production.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

check [react-native-config](https://github.com/luggit/react-native-config)

> Module to expose config variables to your javascript code in React Native, supporting both iOS and Android.